# OpenSSO SP and Attribute Mapper with static values

Tags: opensso

I want to configure attribute mapper form my SP. By default the mapper is com.sun.identity.saml2.plugins.DefaultSPAttributeMapper class. My problem is that I need to put there also a static value. It means that for one of the attribute the value will be always the same, it will be a simple string. Is there any way to do that using the default mapper class or I need to write my own mapper class? If the default doesn't provide such functionality maybe there is other mapper that I can use for that?

Answer (score 0):

https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-2184 is a related issue here, which is already fixed, but not yet in any released versions. This means that there is no out of box solution for static attribute mapping in the existing versions, you need to implement your own AttributeMapper and use that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default attribute mapper as a template. Add code in there to check for the local variable with a prefix of "constant:" following by the constant value. That way, it won't query the LDAP for the local variable. You can map it to any SAML attribute as you would normally.